# Viewport ambient occlusion quality after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: 3d-view

I have been working with Blender for a couple years on Windows 7 at work (with no issues), they just upgraded all the computers to Windows 10 and now my viewport doesnt seem to draw things correctly anymore. Does anyone know what settings I should be looking to change or what is happening here?

[image]

It didn't look like this on Windows 7

[image]

Comment: most likely the drivers for the gpu were affected by the upgrade. check that you have drivers that are made for the new os. Nothing to be done in blender.

Comment: I have Nvidia GTX 980 Ti (x2) cards and I have updated to the latest driver for Windows 10 (only 1 driver available) and the problem still persist. Anyone have any other ideas, or do I have to live with this for now?

Comment: Yes I can, I will go that route, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well after playing around, I have updated all drivers and reinstalled Blender. It looks like if I just turn off ambient occlusion in viewport the problem dissapears.

[image]